# Wordpress 3.6 - archive.php doesn't get triggered

Tags: archives, wp-get-archives, archive-template

I made a custom theme and just created an archive.php file. 
When I try to access `http://localhost/wordpress/?m=201308` for example it just triggers my index.php template. The link was generated by `wp_get_archives()` and should be right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you have a conflict with a plugin. Deactivate all of your active plugins then test. If that doesn't work, test with the default Twenty Twelve or Twenty Thirteen theme.

Comment: Just tested this with a brand new 3.6 and cannot duplicate the problem.

Comment: You were right, it was a plugin which caused the problem. Should have thought of that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is a plugin that causes this. Best way is to disable them one by one. Maybe the plugin has a template which is overriding it.